# How to set the default PostgreSQL schema in Play?

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

We are using Play Framework 2.1 in our web application. We want to explicitly set the database schema (not `public` schema) in our PostgreSQL database that's the application's database. How can I set it ?

Comment: Are you talking about using evolution scripts or what? Otherwise just use whatever schema you want in the database using psql. Or did I completely misunderstand?

Comment: When I try to access a table from database, I get PersistenceException. Because system couldnt find the table.It assumes that I use public schema, therefore somehow I should tell the framework to use the othername schema.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, from what I have tried before. You should define your `schema` name for each Model you want to. It should be like this:

```
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "schema2")
public class TableOnSchema2 extends Model {
  ...
}
```

Maybe this solution would make an additional effort to define each Model with schema name. Because, I don't know whether there is configuration value can be set for specifying default database scheme for the application. But it works for me!

Hope this would help you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

If your tables are all located outside of the public schema, the best thing to do, is to change the search_path for your application user:

```
alter user your_appuser set search_path = 'schema1';
```

If you have multiple schemas, you can add all of them:

```
alter user your_appuser set search_path = 'schema1,schema2,public';
```

Don't forget to `commit` this statement. The change will only have affect after the user logs in the next time. Existing connections will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Playframework 2.8.x using Scala example:

We can add the below entry in `application.conf`:

```
db {
  # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
  # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

  default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
  default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres?currentSchema=backoffice"
  default.username = "user"
  default.password = "password"
}
```

Play framework will create a default connection pool with these parameters.
Postgres driver basically gives the ability to define the default schema in conneciton url using `?currentSchema=backoffice` from `version 9.4` onwards.

A Dao object can use this database as below:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.{DBApi, Database, DefaultDBApi}

class PostgresDao @Inject()(backofficeDB : Database) {
  val backofficeDb = backofficeDB
  //some more methods

}
```